# JavaScript deletes the text in my textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple buttons with the `rel` attribute. I called them `rel1`, `rel2` etc.

The rels contains data, that I retrieve with Javascript.

When I click on the button the button needs to send run a second JavaScript. The second JavaScript sends the `rel` to a textbox.

So far the script is working. But when I click on the button for the second `rel` the first textbox, that is filled with the data of `rel1` gets empty.

Does someone know what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Here is the script for button1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#grid1').DataTable({
      "bprocessing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "response1.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "error": function(){
          $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
        }
      },
      "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 6,
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          return  '<button type="button" id="product_select1" rel1="'+data+'" onclick="getProduct1()">Button</button>';
        }
      } ]              
    });   
  });
</script>
```

This scripts sends the data to the textbox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').on('click', '.selectClass', function () {
    var product_txt1         = $(this).attr('rel1');

    $("#product_txt1").val(product_txt1);
    modal1.style.display = "none";

  });     
</script>
```

Maybe its neccesary. Here is my second script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#grid2').DataTable({
      "bprocessing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "ajax": {
        "url": "response2.php",
        "type": "POST",
        "error": function(){
          $("#employee_grid_processing").css("display","none");
        }
      },
      "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 6,
        "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
          return  '<button type="button" id="product_select1" rel2="'+data+'" onclick="getProduct2()">Button</button>';
        }
      } ]              
    });   
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('body').on('click', '.selectClass', function () {
    var product_txt2         = $(this).attr('rel2');

    $("#product_txt2").val(product_txt2);
    modal2.style.display = "none";

  });     
</script>
```

Comment: "But when I click on the button for the second rel the first textbox, that is filled with the data of rel1 gets empty." I can't understand it. Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I made something in jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/pvf2fws5/ . When I click on `Button 1` in `textfield1` I get the data (data=1). When I click on `Button 2`, `textfield1` gets empty and `textfield2` is filled with data (data=2).

Comment: Your click event handlers are both bound based on the same element class (and in your fiddle no elements have that class), but then they assume the current element (`this`) will have an attribute with a unique name and they output to an element with a specific ID. This doesn't make sense. You need either separate handlers bound to specific elements, or, better, one generic handler bound based on class that used DOM navigation to figure out which input is associated with the clicked button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you click one button, it triggle all click function. Because you handle click function by class. You need to specify your buttons by unique ID and handle click function by that ID. Either you can merge your click function like that:

```
$('body').on('click', '.selectClass', function () {
    var product_txt1         = $(this).attr('rel1');
    var product_txt2         = $(this).attr('rel2');
    if(product_txt1 != null && product_txt1 != undefined){
        $("#product_txt1").val(product_txt1);
        modal1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if(product_txt2 != null && product_txt2 != undefined){
        $("#product_txt2").val(product_txt2);
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }

  });
```